# What does it mean for the Fourier Transform of a function to be bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-transform, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

I am currently going through the [CBMM course](http://www.mit.edu/~9.520/fall17/#readings) on statistical learning theory. Towards the [end of their class](https://youtu.be/9-oxo_k69qs?t=4608) on Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Spaces, the lecturer gives the following hypothesis set as an example.

$$
\mathcal{H} = \{ f \: | \: \forall w \in \mathbb{R}, \: \hat{f}(w) \in \; [-\gamma, \gamma]\}, \quad 0 < \gamma < \infty
$$

The lecturer then discusses the Reproducing Kernel for $\mathcal{H}$.

The lecturer seems to imply that such a hypothesis set is limited in the sense that each function in the set is bounded in terms of frequency. In other words, the set contains functions that have bounded support in the Fourier domain and that functions can only be composed of frequencies within a given interval, specified via $\gamma$.

From my limited understanding of Fourier Transforms, it seems to me that the membership condition on $\mathcal{H}$ is simply saying that no component frequency can "form" too much of the function. In other words, each function in $\mathcal{H}$ can only contain "so much" of frequency $w$. **So my question is, how should I interpret the membership condition on $\mathcal{H}$? Should I think of it as eliminating all functions that contain frequencies outside the window specified by $\gamma$, or as eliminating functions which are dominated by a single component frequency?** I have limited experience with the Fourier Transform, only having really seen it in the context of Computer Vision tasks, so I assuming that my misunderstanding may be down to this.

Comment: The set that you write down is not even a vector space. What is probably meant is $\{f : \widehat{f}(\xi)=0 \text{ for } \xi \in \Bbb{R} \setminus [-\gamma,\gamma]\}$. This is indeed a reproducing kernel space.

Comment: The set was written in the lecture as $
\mathcal{H} = \{ \hat{f} \: | \: \forall w \in \mathbb{R}, \: \hat{f}(w) \in \; [-\gamma, \gamma]\}, \quad 0 < \gamma < \infty
$ but I assumed that the first hat was a notational mistake. Would such a change make the lecturers assertion make any sense?

Comment: No, that still does not solve the problem. What could have been meant (but is essentially the same as what I wrote in my comment above) is $\{f : \text{supp} \,\widehat{f} \subset [-\gamma,\gamma]\}$, that is, the *support*  $ \widehat{f}$ should be contained in $[-\gamma,\gamma]$. One of the issues with requiring a condition on the size of pointwise values (of $\widehat{f}$) is that even if this holds for $f$, it will be violated for $c f$ where $c$ is sufficiently large.

Comment: I see, thank you. I am fairly certain your original comment was what the lecturer was aiming to define.